# SQL Update more than one Table

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have a problem using Update command, using MSSQL 2008EP.
`

```
update RowTable1
set RowTable1.Lnum=B1.Lnum, RowTable1.H2Entry= B1.Entry,
from RowTable1 b 
inner join Header1 a on Entry1= Entry1
inner join RowsOfHeader2 B1 on B1.Item=b.Code and B1.LNum=b.LNum and B1.Entry=@VarEntry
left join Header2 B2 on B2.Entry= B1.Entry
where b.Entry=@Header2_var;
```

`
In this case I have to update the Table RowsOfHeader2 as well as  Header2 and Maybe the Header 1. But I don't want to do this in separate statements... Is there an Option to do this in one Statement

Best regards
Oliver

Comment: No. You will need to run two statements to update two tables.

Comment: Hi, yes that's what I'm doing at this time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way in MS SQL, that one can update multiple tables in single UPDATE Statement.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, then this can be achievable using MERGE statement using CHANGES keyword. But this is available from SQL 2012 onwards.